# How to solve "Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: RequestLimitExceeded => Request limit exceeded." when executing a Chef cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby, chef

I am not an expert in Chef. I am trying to deploy a network infrastructure on AWS. When I execute the cookbook that I uploaded to my Chef Server using knife, a lot of API requests are made to AWS to configure the infrastructure, apparently so many in such a short timespan that AWS blocks the requests and this failure happens eventually:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-66-250-88:~/chef$ knife deployment resize -E core_1 -V
[...]
INFO: Creating security groups...
INFO: Adding rule {:ip_protocol=>:tcp, :min=>7000, :max=>7000, :group=>"sg-04463cd014cc1562c"} to mme-pgw
INFO: Adding rule {:ip_protocol=>:tcp, :min=>9160, :max=>9160, :group=>"sg-04463cd014cc1562c"} to mme-enb
[...]
ERROR: Fog::Compute::AWS::Error: RequestLimitExceeded => Request limit exceeded.
```

I have researched (https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2/issues/453), and I understand that a potential solution is simply slowing down the rate of requests done subsequently, for example, putting a SLEEP in the Ruby script to pause for a few seconds between request. Understood, easy, awesome:

```
sleep 3
```

**...And no idea where to put that.**

Does anyone know where would I have to place that code, inside which file or function?

Maybe on "ec2_server_create_spec.rb" or somewhere else? Inside what function?

Do I have to "compile" the script afterwards whatsoever?

**I tried everything I believe reasonable on my side, I have failed. Any suggestions on what to modify?**

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the file and script where the SLEEP could be put to throttle down the speed of the requests. It worked.

It was specific to my deployment scripts, so I cannot share where exactly since every case is different.